# Is booting from CD necessary?

Tags: boot

I see "burn a CD with x" advice on the internet. Then you boot from the CD and repair something that's preventing Windows from booting.

Is it necessary to use a CD or will a USB drive substitute 100% of the time? As long as a USB port is available.

Comment: As long as the pc support boot from USB devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A USB drive can be substituted for a CD most of the time when making accurate, error-free bootable media, and it also eliminates the risk of creating a badly burnt CD. There are many programs available for making Linux live USBs. [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) is one of the best ones. Click the *Supported Distros* tab on the linked webpage to show the list of supported Linux distributions. Universal USB Installer is updated regularly, as the supported Linux distributions are updated, so it is best to download the latest version.

Comment: I like Universal USB Installer :)